# Handle language change within iOS App in auto layout

Tags: ios, swift, localization, autolayout

In our app, we have to support English and Arabic languages but the language changing option is available within the app itself. Earlier we have handled the right to left and left to right language changes in code.

From iOS 9 onwards, designed the UI with auto layout will be handled this properly, while changing the language in iPhone settings.

As per my requirement, we have changed the language within the app and updated the "AppleLanguages" key directly. But the storyboard is not updating properly. Once I force quit the app and relaunch it, then it working fine.

I need clarifications in that,
Is there any solution to change this (language within the app) without restarting the app?
If No, for restarting the app, Can I show an Alert and quit the app (by using exit(0))? Is this will approved by app review team?

Comment: @Netra how this library will help him with UI?

Comment: you can use exit(0)  but then apple will not let you put app to app store

Comment: @Netra, no I have not used any library. I have used localization to change the translations only. Rest, I need to change the layout in opposite direction. So when I change "AppleLanguages" key, it works fine but when I restart application.

Comment: @Lu_ , I need to upload it on appstore as well.

Answer (score 3):

> I need clarifications in that, Is there any solution to change this
>   (language within the app) without restarting the app?

Yes, there is! if you are already handled changing the language by checking `AppleLanguages` global key and using Auto Layout, it should be easy to do such a functionality.

The solution would be switching the *lproj* bundle in order to get it localized without restarting the app, you should do *Method Swizzling* to achieve it.

I'd recommend to check Working with [Internationalization and Localization in swift](https://medium.com/@dark_torch/working-with-localization-in-swift-4a87f0d393a4) article, it will guides you clearly to do it from scratch (It works fine for me). After following along with it, the output should be similar to:

[image]

---

Also, you might want to check [Localize-Swift](https://github.com/marmelroy/Localize-Swift) library (Actually, I didn't use it).

Hope this helped.

Comment: nice you save my time. Thanks.